# React Native Reanimated Problem Failed to Create Worklet

Tags: react-native, react-native-reanimated

react reanimated cannot create worklet even I already added plugin to babel config, and already put it in the last array

The error:
ERROR  TypeError: Cannot read property 'isConfigured' of undefined

ERROR  Error: [Reanimated] Failed to create a worklet. See https://docs.swmansion.com/react-native-reanimated/docs/guides/troubleshooting#failed-to-create-a-worklet for more details.

Tried to add plugin to babel, but still the same problem. tried to run npx start with clean cache but still same problem, even tried to re build the app.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.